# Handle Build-Number for Maven Release Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

Say I have an artifact with version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (in the SVN). When I call Maven Release Plugin, I want it to build version 1.0.0-1, but leave the SVN at 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. The next release then should be 1.0.0-2 (still with 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in the SVN) etc.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

PS: If the build number should better be determined by a build server as Jenkins, I would also be glad to hear about that.

Comment: Really build version `1.0.0-1` instead of `1.0.1`? The question is what is the meaning `-1` or `-2`  ? This means there had been changes between `1.0.0-1` and `1.0.0-2` ? From my point of view this should be named `1.0.0` and `1.0.1`...(semver!)..Or if you like to express a so called build number with it what should it express? Just another build?

Comment: You can create a branch via `release:branch` with supplemental options to change the version on the branch..or use the build number maybe from Jenkins to fit into this model?

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I am not really sure yet if this is the right way, I am just mimicking the behaviour of our "old" release system (pre-maven-era).